# Problemas con Webservice SOAP

Tags: java, webservice, soap

Tengo una pequeña duda ya que la aplicación que usaba este webservice ha dejado de funcionar. La traza que me muestra en el terminal hace referencia a ello. No se si tengo que volver a crear uno nuevo o modificar. Nunca me habia mostrado un fallo asi.

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"emailActive"). Expected elements are <{}gracePeriod>,<{}resetPassword>,<{}lastLogin>,<{}lastAuthAttempt>,<{}firstTimeLogin>,<{}passwordHistory>,<{}challengeResponseFailCount>,<{}login>,<{}pswdResetToken>,<{}managedSysId>,<{}password>,<{}requestorSessionID>,<{}requestClientIP>,<{}currentLoginHost>,<{}id>,<{}locked>,<{}pwdChanged>,<{}lowerCaseLogin>,<{}createDate>,<{}smsActive>,<{}objectState>,<{}passwordChangeCount>,<{}active>,<{}smsCodeExpiration>,<{}parentAuditLogId>,<{}userId>,<{}pswdResetTokenExp>,<{}lastLoginIP>,<{}prevLoginIP>,<{}requestorLogin>,<{}provStatus>,<{}createdBy>,<{}managedSysName>,<{}testRequest>,<{}requestorUserId>,<{}lastUpdate>,<{}authFailCount>,<{}pwdExp>,<{}toptActive>,<{}prevLogin>,<{}operation>
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:158)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1190.getLoginByManagedSys(Unknown Source)
    at es.sanitas.gid.web.controller.AbstractController.getUserByPrincipal(AbstractController.java:196)
    at es.sanitas.gid.web.controller.SanitasController.resetPasswordPOST(SanitasController.java:225)
```

Answer (score 1):

a ver lo que entiendo en el error que muestras es que estas enviando datos a un parametro que no existe entre los elementos es decir:

> emailActive

deberia verse dentro de los campos como un:

```
<{}emailActive>
```

otro error que vi no se si fue error al transcribir o si de alli se preduce todo pero seria este:

```
,<{}manag<{}pwdExp>,
```

existe un error con los signos deberia ser algo como:

```
,<{}manag>,<{}pwdExp>,
```

Revisa eso y cuentanos.

Saludos

Comment: muchas gracias!Voy a probar.

Comment: comenta en cualquier caso el resultado, si sirve o si no para seguir buscando la solución.

Comment: Funcionó añadiendo emailActive a mano perfectamente,muchas gracias